# C# Access Dictionary value from array

Tags: c#, dictionary

Say, I have an `string[]` of undetermined length, and a `Dictionary<string, object>`, which contains more Dictionaries of its exact type (or other types, which doesn't matter here).

Now I want to change a value in a `Dictionary` in a `Dictionary` ... in my Dictionary depending on my string array.

Here's a little Visualisation:

```
string[]: { "Human", "Legs", "Walking" }
```

```
Dictionary: 
   ↳ Key "Human":
       ↳ Key "Legs":
           ↳ Key "Walking"
```

I wanna set the value of the key "Walking" in this example (lets just say to `true`)

Now my question is: How do i achive this in C#?

Any answers will be appreciated, please excuse me if i am overthinking this.

Comment: Consider using a type-union instead of `Object` for your `TValue`. What happens if a Value is something other than a dictionary?

Comment: @Dai this is for my prgramming language, if the object is something other than an Dictionary and the key points to it, the value the key points to will be used (like a string or smth). If the Key doesn't exist, an Exception will be thrown.

Comment: "the value the key points to will be used (like a string or smth." - right, but that's what I'm asking you to think about: C# is statically-typed, but using `Object` for `TValue` means you'll need to manually test for every type you want to handle - and that approach won't scale or be maintainable. Generally speaking, if you're using `Object` as a type in C# you're doing something wrong.

Comment: do you have a better idea? no matter what i use, somwhere i will have to check which kind of type it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `Object` for `TValue` you'll need to use the `x is T v` operator to test if an `Object` is another dictionary, e.g. `if( x is Dictionary<String,Object> dict )`.

The difficulty here is that you can't use `x is T v` with a strongly-typed `T` because `IReadOnlyDictionary<K,V>` is not covariant over `V`, even when you know what `K` is (as C# and .NET do not support partially-closed generic types).

...but if you don't need/want exactly-typed types and provided that **all** dictionary objects in your graph are always **exactly** `Dictionary<String,Object>` (and not `Dictionary<String,Int32>` or `Dictionary<String,String>`) then you can do this:

```cs
String[] dictPath = new[] { "Human", "Legs", "Walking" };

Dictionary<String,Object> dictGraph = ...

Object humanLegsWalkingValue = GetValueAtPath( dictGraph, dictPath );

//

static Object? GetValueAtPath( Dictionary<String,Object> root, String[] dictPath )
{
    List<String> breadcrumbs = new List<String>(); // For reporting errors.
    
    Dictionary<String,Object> current = root;
    foreach( String name in dictPath )
    {
        breadcrumbs.Add( name );
    
        if( current.TryGetValue( name, out Object? value ) )
        {
            if( value is Dictionary<String,Object> dict )
            {
                current = dict;
            }
            else
            {
                if( breadcrumbs.Count == dictPath.Length )
                {
                    return value;
                }
                else
                {
                    String valueType = value is null ? "null" : value.GetType().FullName;
                    const String MSG_FMT = "Value at \"{0}\" is not a dictionary but is actually {1}, therefore \"{2}\" is unreachable."

                    throw new InvalidOperationException( String.Format( MSG_FMT, String.Join( ".", breadcrumbs ), valueType, String.Join( ".", dictPath ) ) );
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            const String MSG_FMT = "Could not find name \"{0}\" at \"{1}\" therefore \"{2}\" is unreachable."

            throw new KeyNotFoundException( String.Format( MSG_FMT, name, String.Join( ".", breadcrumbs ), String.Join( ".", dictPath ) ) );
        }
    } 

}
```

To **set** a value, it uses *almost* the exact same logic to walk the dictionary-graph, except it stops 1-step short of the end of `dictPath` and uses that to set an entry in `current`:

```
static void SetValueAtPath( Dictionary<String,Object> root, String[] dictPath, Object newValue )
{
    List<String> breadcrumbs = new List<String>(); // For reporting errors.
    
    Dictionary<String,Object> current = root;
    foreach( ( String name, Int32 idx ) in dictPath.Select( ( n, i ) => ( n, i ) ) )
    {
        breadcrumbs.Add( name );
    
        if( idx == dictPath.Length - 1 )
        {
            current[ name ] = newValue;
            return;
        }
        else if( current.TryGetValue( name, out Object? value ) )
        {
            if( value is Dictionary<String,Object> dict )
            {
                current = dict;
            }
            else
            {
                String valueType = value is null ? "null" : value.GetType().FullName;
                const String MSG_FMT = "Value at \"{0}\" is not a dictionary but is actually {1}, therefore {2} is unreachable."

                throw new InvalidOperationException( String.Format( MSG_FMT, String.Join( ".", breadcrumbs ), valueType, String.Join( ".", dictPath ) );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            const String MSG_FMT = "Could not find name \"{0}\" at \"{1}\" therefore \"{2}\" is unreachable."

            throw new KeyNotFoundException( String.Format( MSG_FMT, name, String.Join( ".", breadcrumbs ), String.Join( ".", dictPath ) ) );
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: Well, getting the Value is not my problem,
"I wanna set Walking in this example" is what i said

Comment: @ChronicalCoding I misread your question, sorry - but your post doesn't say what you want to set the value to.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, but it doesn't really matter. For the sake of an example, lets say, i wanna set Walking to true.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a (direct) answer to your question:

```
string[] strs = new string[] { "Human", "Legs", "Walking" };

Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for(int i=0; i<strs.Length; i++) {
    dict.Add(strs[i],(i>0?strs[i-1]:""));
}

string find = "Human";

if(dict.ContainsKey(find)) {
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Hello: {find}");
    foreach (var item in dict.Where(x=>x.Value==find))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine($"You have: {item.Key}");
        foreach (var item2 in dict.Where(x=>x.Value==item.Key)) 
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"Which can make you: {item2.Key}");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Could not find: {find}");
}
```

output:

```
Hello: Human
You have: Legs
Which can make you: Walking
```

NOTE: It's pretty unclear why the title of your question has `Dictionary` and you start defining an array (`string[]`).